# Can't import Android google-play-services_lib

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, google-maps-api-2

It's second day I've been fighting with Eclipse trying to import Google Maps API v2.
I have tried hundreeds of variant, but the library or is not imported and no accessible from my project or `Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Landroid/UnusedStub;`

Android configurations[1]

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/89/t5p0.jpg/

Configurations - Build path[2]

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/507/nbgo.jpg/

Thank you

Comment: what is the procedure you followed?

Comment: are you sure it is the google maps api the problem? I think the problem is that you are importing something twice with different versions

Comment: I've double checked, no duplicates - problem appears only then I try to add Google Maps lib. Procedure ~ http://umut.tekguc.info/en/content/google-android-map-v2-step-step

Comment: try using the google play services as a jar, you can find it at /sdk/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services_lib/libs. Create first a new project where you import this and see if it works

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This means that somewhere the google play services JAR file is referenced more than once in your project.

Most likely once due to a library project dependency, and possible a second time as an Android dependency (by having the JAR file in your libs folder, or by referencing it some other way using a build configuration).

Remove all other references to Google Play Services and only keep the library project dependency. ADT will do the rest.

Comment: ADT automaticaly ads google-play-services_lib.jar with single UnusedStub.class to Android Dependencies.

Comment: yes, but it doesn't copy the JAR to the project, it's just referenced .. Check if your project or any of your library projects don't reference the google play services JAR file in another way.

Comment: The problem was in a duplicate class in one of dependent projects.